# for i in range(5) and k in range(2): TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python, boolean

I'm sure there is a better way to do the last statement. Just trying to check if dayOfWeek is found in `weekday` or `weekend`

My code so far:

```
dayOfWeek = input('What day is it?\n')

weekDay = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
weekend = ['Saturday', 'Sunday']


for i in range(5) and k in range(2):
    if dayOfWeek != weekDay[i] and dayOfWeek != weekend[k]:
        print("You didn't enter a Day of the week")
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if an item is in a list, just use the `in` operator:

```
if not(DayOfWeek in weekend or DayOfWeek in weekday):
   print('You did not enter a day!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is parsed as

```
for i in (range(5) and (k in range(2))):
```

and it would appear `k` was assigned previously. `range(5)` itself is truthy, so the result of the `and` expression is the truth of the *comparison* `k in range(2)`.

Chain the lists (or rather, their iterators) together with `itertools.chain`, then use `not in`:

```
from itertools import chain

if dayOfWeek not in chain(weekDay, weekend):
    print("You didn't enter a Day of the week")
```